# Authorized JavaScript origins not working localhost

Tags: oauth, gmail-api

Authorized JavaScript origins not working while Create client ID. i am trying to integrate google login from in my html page .. my localhost path is http://localhost/charts/ .. while adding http://localhost/charts/ to Authorized JavaScript origins files textbox showing error like this:Origin URIs must not contain a path or end with "/": http://localhost/charts/..
 if any one  can help me...  here i am sending error screenshot

Comment: Do you find any solution I have the same problem

Answer (score 9):

Try this will work **http://localhost**

hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try removing **/charts** from the URL

```
http://localhost
```

Comment: Thanks for giving answer.. it's not working still it showing error :Origin URIs must not contain a path or end with "/": http://localhost/charts

Comment: For that part, you have to just pare it down to **the domain***. You'll enter paths (such as `/charts`) later.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to follow up a quickstart. I added *http://localhost:8000* to **Authorized Javascript origins**, and then I went right after to load my browser - it didn't work. However it worked after 5 minutes or so. I guess you have to give it some time for the changes on the dashboard to take effect.

Some tips that might help:

- Check if you are using a port and include it on the URIs.
- Check your browser console for possible error information.
- In my case I used python dev local server (http.server) to serve my app.